I have upgraded angular & angular material version 9 to 17. I'm facing several UI distortion issue due to MDC migration and custom typography issue
We are using bootstrap and angular material in our application. We have migrated angular material 9 to 17. it seems there are several changes in the theming and MDC. All input fields are having more spaces than older version.
All elements padding and margins are got changed after migration and UI got collapsed.
After Migration:
After Migration
Before Migration:
Before Migration
Please find the theming changes below,

Angular Material version 9:

`@import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Lato',
  $headline: mat-typography-level(32px, 48px, 700),
  $body-1: mat-typography-level(14px, 22px, 500),
);
@include mat-core($custom-typography);
@include angular-material-theme($cockpit-theme);`


Angular Material version 17:

`@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';
@import '@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config($font-family: 'Lato',
    $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em),
    $headline-2: mat.define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.02em),
    $headline-3: mat.define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.005em),
    $headline-4: mat.define-typography-level(32px, 48px, 700),
    $headline-5: mat.define-typography-level(60px, 48px, 500),
    $headline-6: mat.define-typography-level(48px, 48px, 500),
    $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 22px, 500),
  );
@include mat.core();
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($custom-typography);
@include mat.all-component-themes($cockpit-theme);`

Could someone please suggest me the list of changes needs to be done after MDC migration. I have gone through all the documentation but still not able to find the generic solution.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried running the MDC migration command,
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
some of the mat elements got changed to mat-mdc and some of them are left unchanged with comment.
I have tried implementing custom fix for each issues by adding margin & padding but it seems to be more difficult in large scale applications.
I need an generic fix that resolves all of the issues that caused due to upgradation of Angular material and Bootstrap.
